# How can I seperate a page click from a drag in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to only fire the page click event if a normal page click happens, not when a user clicks somewhere on my page, then drags the mouse to a different location and lets go of the mouse button. Right now the page click event is fired when the user lets go of the mouse button regardless of where he first clicked or how long the mouse button was held down for. I cannot modify any code in the mouse drag, mouse down, or mouse up events unfortunately, so no solution involving these events will work for me.

Comment: Store mousedown position as `Point?` in a private field `_mouseDownPosition`. On mouse up, if `_mouseDownPosition` is not null, and it differs by more than three units from the current mouse position, then the user dragged. Otherwise it's a click. Do whatever you need to and set `_mouseDownPosition = null;`

Comment: @Ed I actually stupidly just thought of the same thing just after posting this. I will try this now and update

Comment: @EdPlunkett is right - that's a standard way of approaching the problem. Though personally rather than use an arbitrary minimal drag distance I refer to [SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.minimumhorizontaldragdistance(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.minimumverticaldragdistance(v=vs.110).aspx). You could also create a utility class with attached properties and events to make it reusable.

Comment: Everything @Grx70 said is right.

Comment: Thanks guys this seemed to have worked!